# Ubuntu 22.04 kernel panic unable to mount root file system

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, mount, filesystem

Last night I upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04, and after doing so I am unable to start the OS properly. I get a kernel panic message:

[ 2.499793 ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

I have tried all my previous kernels in both regular and recovery mode from the Ubuntu Advance options menu and I get the same message.

I think the issue is with my grub file, which I am able to edit by pressing the 'e' key at start up, but I don't know the parameters to change with in the file. But I also might not be correct on this issue.

from what tools I do have access to: a grub command line, and an emacs editor to edit the grub.cfg, I can only edit the setparams grub file.

I do not have access to the sudo command from what I can access, so I can't run sudo grub install or any other command line utility

Please help